# Zusammengezogene Präpositionen und Artikel bei "über" und "unter"

Tags: preposition, article

Ich habe in älteren Büchern manchmal "unter dem" und "über dem" zusammengeschrieben gesehen und zwar als "unterm" und "überm". Ich glaube aber nicht, dass ich dies je in neuer Literatur gesehen hab.

Ich ziehe also den Schluss dies könnte eine veraltete Schreibweise sein. Ist das richtig? Wie ist es, wenn es gesprochen wird?

Gibt es andere ungewöhnlichere Zusammenziehungen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[User unknowns Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32288) bring zurecht [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) in die Debatte ein. Man sieht im ersten angehängten Ngram, dass beide Formen auch heute noch schriftlich verwendet werden, wenngleich sie in der ersten Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts sehr beliebt schienen und *unterm* noch bis ca. 1900 etwas beliebter war.

[image: Ngram von *unterm* und *überm*]

Allerdings sollte man das ins Verhältnis setzen. Heutzutage gibt es eine Reihe von Pflichtzusammensetzungen, darunter fallen *am* und *zum* unter Anderem. Bezieht man diese beiden in die Analyse ein, ergibt sich das folgende Ngram:

[image: Ngram von *unterm*, *überm*, *zum* und *am*]

Noch eindeutiger wird die Sache, wenn man auch *unter, über, zu* und *an* in einem Vergleichs-Ngram darstellen lässt:

[image: Ngram von *unter*, *über*, *zu* und *an*]

Daraus lässt sich schließen, dass *überm* und *unterm* zwar grundsätzlich verwendet werden, allerdings deutlich unterrepräsentiert gegenüber *am* und *zum* sind, vor Allem, wenn man sie jeweils mit den unmodifizierten Präpositionen vergleicht. Auch zu Zeiten, als *unterm* und *überm* noch eine in Prozenten einigermaßen ausdrückbare Verwendung im Textkorpus fanden, überwogen die anderen beiden Präpositionen überproportional.

Damals, weit vor dem 20. Jahrhundert, war die Rechtschreibung noch nicht standardisiert, man schrieb, wie es einem passte. Es hat auch keine Instanz gegeben, die behauptet hätte, diese Zusammenfügung sei statthaft, jene nicht; wie es im 20. Jahrhundert der Duden war. Dennoch gelang es *unterm* und *überm* nicht, sich außerhalb des Mündlichen zu etablieren. Warum, darüber kann man nur spekulieren.

Fazit: Zu keiner Zeit, als eine standardisierte Rechtschreibung vorgeherrscht hätte, waren *unterm* und *überm* erlaubt oder vorgeschrieben. Das Etikett *veraltet* ist demnach falsch. Sie sind aber in der Umgangssprache sehr lebendig (und wie User unknown ebenfalls anmerkt, demnach auch in direkter Rede). Daher wären sie besser als *umgangssprachlich* klassifiziert.

Comment: Schön wäre es gewesen, wenn du das Wort »Fazit« durch »Unterm Strich« ersetzt hättest. :)

Answer (score 5):

Mit [Google-NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unterm%2C%C3%BCberm&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunterm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%BCberm%3B%2Cc0) kann man solche Fragen leicht selbst recherchieren. Man sieht dort: Zwar sind die Formen heute seltener als früher, aber sie sind nicht verschwunden.

Ähnliche Formen sind hinterm (Hinterm Horizont gehts weiter), vorm, aufm, nachm und so weiter, die in wörtlicher Rede auch häufig sind, womöglich regional verschieden.

Womöglich ist die schriftliche Form in Büchern vor allem die Wiedergabe wörtlicher Rede, denn umgangssprachlich ist es verbreitet.

Comment: Duden nennt die Verwendung "umgangssprachlich", außer in festen Wendungen. Und in der Umgangssprache haben diese Zusammenziehungen ihren festen Platz.

Comment: @tofro: Das Wort lag mir auf der Zunge., danke.

Answer (score -2):

Die wohl am häufigsten gebrauchte Zusammenziehung ist "zum", kurz für "zu dem".
Andere sind "zur" - "zu der", "zu ihr"; "am" - "an dem"; "vom" - "von dem". Diese Formen werden bisweilen auch im Beamtendeutsch gebraucht, sie sind also keine reine Umgangssprache.

Comment: *Zu ihr* wird nicht mit *zur* abgekürzt (zumindest nicht standardsprachlich und nicht in der mir bekannten Umgangssprache). Alle anderen Formen sind **standardsprachlich** und werden in jedem Grammatikbuch behandelt; sie nicht anzuwenden ist falsch, wenn nichts extra betont werden soll.